# Should I cite the book and ancient text in my paper?

Tags: citations, philosophy

I'm writing a paper for an undergraduate philosophy class and I am not sure how I should make the citation for the text. I will provide an example.

> However, we do read from the dialogue Apology, that Socrates had a friend named Chaerephon who visited the oracle at Delphi (Plato and Allen 83, 21a).

**1.) Should I include the page numbers and the DK numbers?** The text I'm using is: Plato, and Reginald E. Allen. *The Dialogues of Plato Volume 1*. New Haven: Yale Uni. Press, 1984. Print.

**2.) Furthermore, how would I format the "Ibid." citation?**

Comment: Citation formats are a dime a dozen. Talk to your instructor about what form, if any, they want to see; if they don't care, I'd suggest MLA or APA format for a philosophy class.

Comment: @tonysdg I feel that it is too late to add my professor since this paper is late. Also, no articles have I found concerning whether I should use the both the book AND the ancient text. On  articles on how to cite them separately.

Comment: Is the text a translation then from the ancient Greek? If that's the case, [this site](http://guides.library.duq.edu/c.php?g=232812&p=1545838) might be a useful resource.

Comment: Well that's the question. So if I'm reading in English, it's not the ancient Greek but the DK numbers are the same regardless of language. I thank you kindly for the article but I don't think that answers my question either.

Comment: That's why I'm commenting and not submitting an answer ;-)

Comment: Haha I figured!

Comment: Voting to close the question, asked from an undergraduate point of view. And many questions about citation formatting available already.